# How to resolve this issue with "make" in Visual Studio

Tags: github, makefile, visual-studio-code, firmware, chocolatey

I am attempting to flash firmware for the Odrive motor controller. I am using the recommended Visual Studio Code. I cloned the Github link and intially when I clicked "build firmware" from the "Terminal" dropdown menu, it told me "make is a not a recognized cmdlet etc..." So using another tutorial I downloaded Chocolatey and installed make using `choco install make`

Now when I try to build the firmware in the same manner I get the following error:

`process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, tup --quiet --no-environ-check, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:14: all] Error 2
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1`

Could anyone help me resolve this and get this firmware built?

Comment: I’m not familiar with Odrive, but do they say their toolchain works on Windows? For stuff like this I tend to have better luck compiling/building on Linux.

Comment: It looks like you need `tup` in addition to `make`: http://gittup.org/tup/

Comment: Usually there will be a `README` or `ONBOARDING` file with precise instructions on how to set-up your build environment - is there anything like that in your case?

Comment: @Dai Yes Windows seems to be fine. I do indeed have Tup installed, this is not the issue. When you mention the README file, do you mean from ODrive? They do have this, but I can't seem to find an answer to my issue in there. Here is the link to that page: [https://docs.odriverobotics.com/developer-guide.html]